# How To Make IF And using Python ( tried IF but didn't work , also tried np.where but also not worked)

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Support needed as i want to make logic if and with python but i can't get the result i wanted or error appear
Data frame i got is four column

1- first column under header (Segment) contain only one of two statement [ inbound ] or [outbound]
2- second column under header (Out_going Calls) contain number [ random number like 5,6,0,1,0]
3- Third column under header (POM_Count) contain number [ random number like 5,6,0,1,0]
4-Fourth column under header (Stuff_Time)contain number [ random number like 32400,5000,33660,20000,0]

i need to make if and as shown below
DF[Inbound_Call]=if (DF["segment =inbound"] & DF["Out_going Calls"] =0),0,DF["Stuff_Time"]

DF[Outbound_Call]=if (DF["segment =Outbound"] & DF["POM_Count"] =0),0,DF["Stuff_Time"]

thanks i

```
         Staffed Time  POM_Count  Out_going Calls   Segment
0           33240        0.0                0  Outbound
1           33237        0.0               10       NaN
2           33076        0.0                0  Outbound
3           37848      342.0                0  Inbound
4           38836      429.0                0  Outbound
..            ...        ...              ...       ...
275         32671      146.0                0  Inbound
276         32497      149.0               10  Outbound
277         32663      139.0               13  Inbound
278         32787      238.0                4  Outbound
279         20918       45.0                0  Outbound
```

i tried that code but below error appear

```
PG["St_after_Ded"]=np.where(PG['Segment'] == 'inbound' & PG['Out_going Calls'] == 0, 0, PG["0"]) 

TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [int64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you decribed seems to be sufficiently appropriate to use with the `np.where`, you just need to use the parentheses for each condition between the logic and.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

PG = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

PG["Inbound_Call"] = np.where(
    (PG['Segment'] == 'Inbound') & (PG['Out_going Calls'] == 0), 0, PG['Staffed Time'])

PG["Outbound_Call"] = np.where(
    (PG['Segment'] == 'Outbound') & (PG['POM_Count'] == 0), 0, PG['Staffed Time'])

print(PG)
```

Output from *PG*

```py
   Staffed Time  POM_Count  Out_going Calls   Segment  Inbound_Call  Outbound_Call
0         33240        0.0                0  Outbound         33240              0
1         33237        0.0               10       NaN         33237          33237
2         33076        0.0                0  Outbound         33076              0
3         37848      342.0                0   Inbound             0          37848
4         38836      429.0                0  Outbound         38836          38836
5         32671      146.0                0   Inbound             0          32671
6         32497      149.0               10  Outbound         32497          32497
7         32663      139.0               13   Inbound         32663          32663
8         32787      238.0                4  Outbound         32787          32787
9         20918       45.0                0  Outbound         20918          20918
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you expecting this, for condition with & operator you can use this,

```
df.loc[(df['Segment'] == 'inbound') & (df['Out_going Calls'] == 0), 'Status'] = '0'
print(df)
```

Please provide the desired output format that you need. That may make task easier.

Comment: i tried above but result is NAN . Outbound needed is matched the above logic that if ( segment == inbound & out going call ==0) then outbound (0) if not ( stuff time)

Comment: it's more like excel if and .... = if(and(segment="Inbound",out_going_calls"=0),0,Stuff Time) ...... that how i will do if it was excel